# How to install KDiff3 version 1.9.4 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

How can i install / update KDiff3 version 1.9.4 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have installet Version 1.8.1 (64bit) and want update to the actuell version https://github.com/KDE/kdiff3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, official kdiff3 page is at https://apps.kde.org/kdiff3/ .

Then about newer version. You can install Git-version *1.9.70~git20220123-1~focal1* from some [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eblaze/+archive/ubuntu/kf5) using command below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/kf5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdiff3
```

If you do not like it, remove it with the PPA by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:blaze/kf5
```

---

If you do not like PPAs, you can use 1.9.4 version [from Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kdiff3) as follows:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.kde.kdiff3
```

Comment: Works. Many thanks.